# Selective flyspell mode?

Tags: emacs, highlighting, flyspell

I use `flyspell-mode` when writing blog posts. The problem I'm having is that I blog about code a lot, and `flyspell` predictably highlights most of the "words" in that code as misspellings.

Is there any way to get it to ignore blocks of text between `code` and `pre` tags?

Comment: In addition to my sample answer below, here is another option:  http://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer/345461#345461

Comment: Did you delete your answer here for some reason, @lawlist?

Comment: @Brian Z -- The O.P. made a comment that my answer was "less than stellar" and he / she hasn't accepted it in nearly a year, so I deleted it.